# ArrayList<ObjectLabel> labels = GoogleCloudVision.detectImageLabels(); Not working

Tags: java, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to call GoogleCloudVision to get the image labels into an array. I don't know what to do for the ObjectLabel method which seems to be the problem. The program is meant to take an image file and run it through googles cloud vision and get an array of labels for the image, then based on the array determine what is the image.

this is the error I'm getting.

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\DELL Laptop\Downloads\Exam3Starter\src
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.<init>(WindowsDirectoryStream.java:86)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:533)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:544)
    at GoogleCloudVision.findJsonCredentialsFile(GoogleCloudVision.java:51)
    at GoogleCloudVision.detectImageLabels(GoogleCloudVision.java:80)
    at SeeFood.labelImage(SeeFood.java:57)
    at SeeFood.main(SeeFood.java:83)
```

Code:

```
public static void labelImage(String filename) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO: replace with your implementation
        String userFile = filename;
        JFrame img = new JFrame();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(userFile);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        img.add(label);
        img.pack();
        img.setVisible(true);
        ArrayList<ObjectLabel> labels = GoogleCloudVision.detectImageLabels(userFile);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, labels);
    } // end labelImage

public class ObjectLabel {

    String Label = "";
    float confidence = 2.0F;

    public ObjectLabel(String description, float score) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the entire stack trace. Please copy and paste it into your question instead of using an image.

Comment: thank you for commenting, I just copied and pasted the stack trace now.

Comment: What's the value of the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable?

Comment: From the error it seems the file path you have provided does not match the pattern for image path. Could you try with an image path like C:\Users\DELL Laptop\Downloads\images\file1.jpg ?

Comment: @SandeepMohanty If you look at the stack trace it isn't the image file.